# (Royden Real Analysis) How is this set function $m^{**}$ related to outer measure $m^*$?

Tags: real-analysis

The following question is taken from page $43$ in the $4$th edition 'Real Analysis' by Royden, questoin $22$.

For any set $A$, define $m^{**}(A) \in [0, \infty]$ by
$m^{**}(A) = \inf \{m^*(O) : O\supset A, O \text{ is open}.\}$
How is this set function $m^{**}$ related to outer measure $m^*$?

I manage to prove that for any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $m^{**}(A) = m^*(A)$ when both $m^{**}(A)$ and $m^{*}(A)$ are finite, that is, by considering $m^{**}(A) \leq m^{*}(A) + \varepsilon$ and $m^{*}(A) \leq m^{**}(A) + \varepsilon$.

However, I have problem proving they are equal when at least one of them is infinite.

If $m^*(A) = \infty$, then there exists a collection of disjoint measurable sets $\{ A_k \}_{k \geq 1}$ such that $A = \cup_{k \geq 1}{A_k}$ and $m^*(A_k) < \infty$ for all $k$.

From here, i couldn't proceed to show that $m^*(A) = m^{**}(A)$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A \subset B$ then $m^*(A) \leqslant m^*(B)$ holds in general. If $m^*(A) = +\infty$,  $O$ is open and $A \subset O$, then $m^*(O) \geqslant m^*(A) = + \infty.$

Thus, $m^*(A) = +\infty \implies m^{**}(A) = +\infty.$

The reverse implication follows in that if $m^{**}(A) = +\infty$ then for any open set $O$ with $A \subset O$, we have $m^*(O) = + \infty$. In particular this holds true for any countable union of open intervals covering $A$, whence $m^*(A) = +\infty$.